# Как реализовать Шейпер трафика

Tags: java, сокет

Есть сокеты на Java.
Все данные передаются в виде объектов(хотел как проще, а вышло как обычно)

```
outputStream.writeObject(new Ping());
```

Есть задача реализовать шейпер(или подобное).
Как я вижу работу шейпера:

```
long x = System.nanoTime();
long BytesWrite = outputStream.writeObject(new Ping());
while((BytesWrite / (System.nanoTime() - x))>1000)
{
  sleep(1);
}
```

Проблема в получении **BytesWrite**
Решаема ли она при текущем подходе?(и как?)
Есть ли смысл отказываться от такой модели и городить "свой" формат пакетов и их отправки?
Есть ли в Java что то встроенное для подобных извращений(шейпинг трафика)?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создавать `ObjectOutputStream` каждый раз когда передаете объект. В качестве базового потока использовать `ByteArrayOutputStream` (тоже каждый раз новый). Вытаскивать из него массив байт и передавать его в реальный поток.

PS: Ваш текущий код приведет к утечке памяти так как `ObjectOutputStream` запоминает все отправленные объекты.

PPS: Стандартная сериализация ужасна, постарайтесь избегать ее.

Comment: Оо.. Серьезно нужно каждый раз создавать? это же жесть, во всех "мануалов" для начинающих вот такая запись `final ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());` И оно ведет к утечке?

Comment: Не знаю почему они так пишут. Наверное потому что это будет работать и это проще. В реальности стандартную сериализацию используют крайне редко, в частности и из-за такого рода проблем. Как я уже говорил, она ужасна.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснения, значит придется переписать сериализацию. Остается открытым вопрос, надо ли пересоздавать после каждого пакета Stream ?(если использовать не `ObjectOutputStream` а `OutputStream`)

Comment: Не надо. Эта проблема только с `ObjectOutputStream`